# Using where function on numpy matrices with mixed char and number

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([a,b,1,2,1,1])
```

I want to convert certain numbers to characters. (1 -> k)
result below

```
[a,b,k,2,k,k]
```

I wrote the code

```
a = np.where((a == 1), 'k', a)
```

but I can't use the where function with a mixture of char and numbers. How can I use where function?

Comment: In `np.array([a,b,1,2,1,1])`, what are `a`,`b`?  Did you look at a `a` after creating it?  Check the `dtype`?

Answer (score 0):

This works with an object dtype:

```
a = np.array(['a','b',1,2,1,1], dtype=object)

np.where((a == 1), 'k', a)
```

Output:

```
array(['a', 'b', 'k', 2, 'k', 'k'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `a` definition to make sense:

```
In [12]: a = np.array(['a','b',1,2,1,1])
In [13]: a
Out[13]: array(['a', 'b', '1', '2', '1', '1'], dtype='<U21')
```

This is an array of strings - no numbers; With that in mind it is easy to change the strings `'1'`:

```
In [14]: a=='1'
Out[14]: array([False, False,  True, False,  True,  True])
In [15]: np.where(a=='1', 'k', a)
Out[15]: array(['a', 'b', 'k', '2', 'k', 'k'], dtype='<U21')
```

or changing the '2':

```
In [16]: a[a=='2'] = 'k'
In [17]: a
Out[17]: array(['a', 'b', '1', 'k', '1', '1'], dtype='<U21')
```

You could switch to object dtype array, to keep strings and numbers.  But be careful.  In many ways such an array is the same as a list.